# Equation with Riemann zeta function and its derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

In [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82463813.pdf), there is an equation that involves Riemann zeta function and its derivative:

\begin{equation}
\frac{-\zeta'(\sigma)}{\zeta(\sigma) - 1} = k  \quad\quad\quad\quad(1)
\end{equation}

where $\sigma$ denotes unique solution $\sigma >  1$, $k \in  \mathbb{R}^+$. In the paper there is formula for calculation of $\sigma$:
\begin{equation}
\sigma = 1 + k + (1-\gamma)k^2 + ...
\end{equation}
where $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant. I evaluated this in MATLAB and this seems to yield close enough results. However, I do not understand how to solve (1) for $\sigma$.

Comment: Expand the ratio of zetas into a power series in $\sigma-1$ and use series reversion (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) to express $\sigma-1$ as a power series of $k$. Add $1$ to both sides and you have the result.

Comment: In particular, we won't be able to algebraically solve for $\sigma$ exactly; we can only find approximations to the solution.

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Comment: Now, you have almost the exact solution at the price of a cubic equation which has an analytical solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you misread the equation. In the paper, the rhs is $\frac{\log (x)}{m}$ while the expansion at the top of page $85$ is in terms of $\frac m{\log (x)}$.

Anyway, considering
$$-\frac{\zeta '(x)}{\zeta (x)-1}=k$$ around $x=1$, we have
$$\zeta (x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+\gamma -\gamma _1 (x-1)+\frac{1}{2} \gamma _2 (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ So, we know the expansion of $\zeta '(x)$ and lon division gives
$$-\frac{\zeta '(x)}{\zeta (x)-1}=\frac{1}{x-1}+(1-\gamma )+$$ $$\left(2 \gamma _1+1-2 \gamma +\gamma ^2\right)
   (x-1)+$$ $$\left(2 \gamma _1+(1-\gamma ) \gamma _1-2 \gamma  \gamma _1-\frac{3 \gamma
   _2}{2}+1-3 \gamma +3 \gamma ^2-\gamma ^3\right) (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ which is quite good up to $x=5$.

Using series reversion (as @Gary commented)
$$x=1+\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1-\gamma }{k^2}+\frac{2 \left(\gamma _1+1-2 \gamma +\gamma
   ^2\right)}{k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$$

**Edit**

If I had to solve the equation for $x$, I would prefer to solve instead
$$-\frac{\zeta (x)-1}{\zeta '(x)}=a \qquad  \text{with} \qquad a=\frac 1k$$ which is much better conditioned.

A nonlinear regression gives (the coefficients were made rational), with $R^2 > 0.999999$, as an *estimate*,
$$x_0=\frac{1-\frac{65 }{92}a-\frac{82 }{273}a^2+\frac{27 }{125}a^3} { 1-\frac{171 }{101}a+\frac{88 }{95}a^2-\frac{16 }{99}a^3}$$

Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 2.91932 &  2.91746 \\
 2 & 1.64084 &  1.64232 \\
 3 & 1.38780 &  1.38992 \\
 4 & 1.27823 &  1.28026 \\
 5 & 1.21697 &  1.21881 \\
 6 & 1.17784 &  1.17949 \\
 7 & 1.15067 &  1.15216 \\
 8 & 1.13070 &  1.13205 \\
 9 & 1.11541 &  1.11664 \\
 10 & 1.10332 &  1.10445
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

Another possible solution is to build the $[3,3]$ Padé approximant around $x=1$ and, making all coefficients rational have
$$f(x)=-\frac{\zeta (x)-1}{\zeta '(x)}\sim \frac {t+\frac{157 }{1308}t^2+\frac{2 }{309}t^3} {1+\frac{260 }{479}t+\frac{29 }{321}t^2+\frac{1}{224}t^3}=g(x)\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=x-1$$ which is quite good for $1 \leq x \leq 20$. To give an idea
$$\Phi=\int_0^{10} \Big[f(x)-g(x)\Big]^2\,dx=6.35 \times 10^{-6}$$
$$\Phi=\int_0^{20} \Big[f(x)-g(x)\Big]^2\,dx=4.56 \times 10^{-4}$$

Using $g(x)$, we then just need to solve the cubic equation in $t$
$$-1+\left(k-\frac{260}{479}\right) t+\left(\frac{157 k}{1308}-\frac{29}{321}\right)
   t^2+\left(\frac{2 k}{309}-\frac{1}{224}\right) t^3=0$$ The discriminant is always negative and using the hyperbolic method, we have the explicit solution for $t(k)$.

Repeating the same calculations as above

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 2.91750 &  2.91746 \\
 2 & 1.64232 &  1.64232 \\
 3 & 1.38992 &  1.38992 \\
 4 & 1.28026 &  1.28026 \\
 5 & 1.21881 &  1.21881 \\
 6 & 1.17949 &  1.17949 \\
 7 & 1.15216 &  1.15216 \\
 8 & 1.13205 &  1.13205 \\
 9 & 1.11664 &  1.11664 \\
 10 & 1.10445 &  1.10445
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for extensive answer. I am not in the field, so if you could further clarify "we know the expansion of ′() and lon division gives". Thank you in advance.

Comment: @dumpram. Just differentiate the series of $\zeta (x)$ !! Long division does not need explanation (I hope). Cheers :-)